# Use precompiled headers in C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, precompiled-headers, pch

I have a project with the following structure

```
root/
  CMakeLists.txt
  mylibrary.hpp
  test/
    CMakeLists.txt  // included from root's CMakeLists
    A.cpp //includes<mylibrary.hpp>
    B.cpp // also
    C.cpp // also
    ...
    Z.cpp // also
```

I am conviced that the compilation (of the tests) can be speed up by precompiling (pch) `mylibrary.hpp`

**How do I tell CMake to use precompiled header if it can?**

Also, the project uses different compilers, gnu, clang, nvcc, intel, (different build configurations) so the generation of the precompiled headers may not be always available.

The CMake has all the test working otherwise.
I tried using `target_precompile_headers` as in

```
  target_precompile_headers(A PUBLIC ../mylibrary.hpp)
  target_precompile_headers(B PUBLIC ../mylibrary.hpp)
  ...
```

But it is actaully **slower** because it generates a new instance of the precompiled header for each test. (`PRITAVE` gives the same (slow) result, using `INTERFACE` doesn't do anything different).

Comment: My recommendation: spend several days in reading documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [cmake](https://cmake.org/). By experience, in *some* cases with *some* versions of GCC, precompiled headers can be slower.

Comment: Have you tried using the `REUSE_FROM` option? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_precompile_headers.html